# how to add the effect of two hazard rates (dependent data)?

Tags: survival, hazard

I'm not sure the right procedure to add two hazard functions. Say I have two experimetal conditions goberned by the following probabilities

hazard rate function 1:
It is characterized by the probabilities 0.33, 0.43, and 0.23 and it produces the hazard rates 0.33, 0.66, and 1.

hazard rate function 2:
It is characterized by the probabilities 0.33, 0.00, and 0.66, and it produces the hazard rates 0.33, 0.00, and 1.

Since these hazard functions are conditional probabilities, how can I add the two hazard functions to study the resulting hazard rate in the same sample of participants (dependent data)?

Any help will be much appreciated

Best

Comment: *Competing hazards* might be a relevant key phrase.

Comment: It's hard to tell from what you've written just what those hazard functions represent and what you want to accomplish by combining them. Please edit the question to say more about the study and your goals, or it will be difficult to provide a helpful answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion! Indeed I found this very interesting page to start my diligence https://www.publichealth.columbia.edu/research/population-health-methods/competing-risk-analysis
All the best